# На каком языке лучше всего начать изучать программирование

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, python

я начинающий в этом деле и даже не могу назвать себя программистом. Я знаю английский на уровне beginner и у меня огромные планы с этой профессией. Мне лучше учиться читать сразу книги на английском языке или сейчас лучше на русском? Нужны ваши советы, а также если не трудно, дайте пару ссылок на бесплатные сайты по изучению английского. Спасибо

Comment: Лучше и не начинай, там муть полнейшая, даже если ты будешь знать все эти языки, которые ты перечислил в метках, ты все равно не станешь программистом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самую первую очередь, тебе нужно изучить алгоритмизацию. Это позволит мыслить "как программист" - умение разделить задачу на чёткую последовательность действий и условий. Человек знающий алгоритмизацию сможет писать на любом языке, т.к. ему понадобится лишь узнать, какими командами в синтаксисе нужного языка выражается действие, которое необходимо сделать.

Второе - выбрать направление. У программирования много отраслей, порой достаточно далёких друг от друга. Можно писать приложения, сайты, программы для мобильных устройств, игры, серверные, клиентские, и так далее. Когда направление выбрано - можно начинать смотреть видеоуроки для начинающих на ютубе, читать книги, и тд.

Третий этап - когда уже получены базовые знания синтаксиса, переписано несколько примеров из обучения - стараться комбинировать знания, придумывать что то своё, совмещая знания полученные в процессе обучение.
...ну и так далее

P.S.: По поводу английского - смотри фильмы с субтитрами, пользуйся не-русифицированными программами, но обучаться лучше по возможности используя русскоязычную документацию, т.к. переводя переводчиком с англ можно не понять тонкостей каких то аспектов.

Comment: Cпасибо, я очень ценю твои советы.

Comment: В качестве благодарности можно поставить плюс, или подтвердить ответ как правильный =)